# Given the array A and the number K create array B where B[i] = min(A[i], A[i+1].. A[i + K - 1])

Tags: arrays, algorithm, deque

Given an array of integers, `A`, and an integer value, `K`, create array `B` where `B[i]` is the minimum value in the sub-array `A[i], A[i+1], ..., A[i+K-1]`. Note that `B.length` will be equal to `A.length - K`.

For example for `K = 3` and `A=[1,2,3,4,0,1,2]` the solution is  `B=[1,2,0,0,0]`.

```
A  =  [1,2,3,4,0,1,2]
       _____| | | | |      
B[1] = 1      | | | | 
         _____| | | | 
B[2] =   2      | | | 
           _____| | | 
B[3] =         0  | | 
             _____| | 
B[4] =         0    | 
               _____| 
B[5] =         0
```

A solution for O(kn) time complexity is as follows:

```
public static int[] createArray(int[] arr, int k) {
    int[] result = new int[arr.length];
    for (int i = 0; i <= arr.length - k; i++) {
        int curSmallestVal = arr[i];
        for (int j = i + 1; j < i + k; j++) {
            curSmallestVal = Math.min(curSmallestVal, arr[j]);
        }
        result[i] = curSmallestVal;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Can you provide a more elegant solution with O(n) runtime? (potentially with using queues)

Update with the O(n) solution:

```
public static int[] getMinSlidingWindow(int[] arr, int k) {
    int[] result = new int[arr.length-k+1];
    Deque<Integer> queue = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    //initialize sliding window
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        if (!queue.isEmpty() && arr[queue.getLast()] >= arr[i])
            queue.removeLast();
        queue.addLast(i);
    }

    for (int i = k; i < arr.length; i++) {
        result[i-k] = arr[queue.getFirst()];
        while (!queue.isEmpty() && arr[queue.getLast()] >= arr[i])
            queue.removeLast();
        queue.addLast(i);
        while (!queue.isEmpty() && queue.getFirst() <= i-k)
            queue.removeFirst();
    }

    result[arr.length-k] = arr[queue.removeFirst()]; 

    return result;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. Could you provide a better example? What is K and where does it come from?

Comment: The example is improved.

Comment: Thank you, Gergely Orosz. It is good to use math equation when words are not working well.

Comment: This question would be better suited for [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a double ended queue (one that supports adding pushing and poppoing from the front and the back) with a bit of extra logic you can construct a solution that runs O(n).

Here's the pseudocode for a solution.

```
void getMaxSlidingWindow(int[] A, int k) {
    int[] B = new int[A.length - k];
    // Store the indexes of A in Q
    // Q.front(): index of smallest element in the window, Q.back(): index of the largest one in the window
    DobuleEndedQueue<int> Q = new DobuleEndedQueue<int>(); 

    for(int i=0; i<k; i++) {
       // Fill up the double ended queue for the first k elements
       // Remove elements that we would ignore because they're bigger than the next one in the window
       while(!Q.empty() && A[i] <= A[Q.back()]) {
          Q.popBack();
       }
       Q.pushBack(i);
    }

     for(int i=k; i < A.length; i++) {
       B[i - k] = A[Q.front()]; // The first element in the queue is the index of the smallest element in the window
       // Add the current element to the queue. Before we do, remove all elements that we would ignore immediately because they're bigger than the current one
       while(!Q.empty() && A[i] <= A[Q.back()]  ) {
          Q.popBack();
       }
       Q.pushToBack(i);
       // Remove any index from the front of the queue which is no longer in the window
       while(!Q.empty() && Q.front() <= i-k) {
         Q.popFront();
       }
    }
    B[A.length - k] = A[Q.front()];
}
```

**The time complexity** of this solution is O(n): we iterate through all elements once and either add or remove them to the double ended queue once. The maximum operations done are 2n, which is a O(n) complexity.

For this solution to work you need to implement the double ended queue data structure with the following operations:

```
class DobuleEndedQueue
int front(), void pushFront(int n), void popFront() // peeks at the front element, adds and removes to the front
int back(), void pushBack(int n) , void popBack() // same for the back element
```

Further explanation for the algorithm with a simple example:

- Iterate through the first k elements and insert these as indexes into a double ended Q data structure so that A[Q.front()] is the smallest element and A[Q.back()] is the largest element in the window.
- As we build up the window, throw out "unnecessary" elements from this queue: both smallest elements that would not be counted and elements which are outside of the window
- Example of building the queue for A=[8, 6, 9, 2] and k-3
- 1. Q = [0], (Insert 0 to the back of Q because A[0] is the smallest element we've seen.)
- 2. Q = [1], (A[1] < Q.back() so pop the back element and replace it with 1. We do this because A[0] will be irrelevant when looking for the smallest number from now on.)
- 3. Q = [1, 2], B=[8] (A[2] is > Q.back(), so we just add 2 on to the Q. B[0] will be the smallest item in Q, which is A[Q.first()], that is A[1])
- 4. Q = [3], B=[8, 2] (A[4] is smaller than all elements in Q, so we pop all of them. B[1] will be the smallest item in Q, A[Q.first()], that is A[3]

Comment: What is the time complexity of your algorithm??

Comment: As detailed in the answer it's O(n)

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to achieve `O(n)` time complexity using standard sliding window minimum algorithm with a deque. Here is it's detailed description: http://people.cs.uct.ac.za/~ksmith/articles/sliding_window_minimum.html

Comment: I think you should include a brief explanation of the alogrithm from the page so that if the link is invalid in future , others will get information from your explanation

Comment: still, they are saying amortized `O(n)` which means it can still be `O(kn)` in worst case

Comment: @MujtabaHasan No. It is always `O(n)`. It is never `O(nk)`.

Comment: @VikramBhat This algorithm is well-known. Its name is sufficient to find out more about it. The link is just for convenience.

Comment: I quote it from that page "The idea of lazily deleting elements is a salient one, but by putting in a bit more effort when inserting an element into the window we can get **amortized O(1)** run-time".. To maintain the list sorted and removing any element greater than the current one, they have to remove all the elements from the back greater than it. Please check it more carefully..

Comment: @MujtabaHasan Are you sure that you understand the meaning of the word "amortized" properly?

Comment: Yaa. that's what I am saying, It's only amortized `O(1)` and certainly greater than `O(1)` in average case. So if you accurately count number of computations for whole array, it won't be exactly O(n). It can only be in average case. Consider a case where several arrays sorted in ascending and descending order are appended. By this method, you have to remove all elements greater than current number at many indices. So, overall it would be close to `O(n*k)`

Comment: @MujtabaHasan It is `O(n)` in the worst case. Please, read the definition of amortized complexity. Here is an article about it: http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spring06/cos423/Handouts/Amortized.pdf

Comment: If it is worst case scenario, why do they use the word **"amortized"** and not **worst** case. I went through the paper. The first line of abstract in the paper says "amortization or averaging over time". Please read more carefully.

Comment: @MujtabaHasan Average here means: given `n` queries, the total number of operations is `O(n)`, even though one operation might require more then `O(1)` actions. So you actually misunderstand it.

Comment: Is there any worst case constant upper bound for it to be `O(n)`

Comment: @MujtabaHasan Yes, for one operation the upper bound is `O(n)`. However, all `n` operations require `O(n)` operations in total in the worst case.

Comment: So, does it mean `O(n^2)` in total in worst case..

Comment: @MujtabaHasan Nope, it doesn't. As I have said before, `O(n)` is an upper bound for a total number of operations.

Comment: Is there any upper bound of constant multiple of ` n` for it to be `O(n)` if it is worst case complexity.

Comment: @MujtabaHasan Yes. Each element is added to the deque only once. Each element is removed from the deque only once. Thus, C = 2.

Comment: and how many elements are deleted

Comment: while removing and adding elements, u may have to compare more than twice.. and it can certainly be more than two for a worst case scenario.. consider the case, the deque is {1, 6, 7, 2, 4, 2} as given on the page and now u want to add 5, u will have to remove 6 and 7. so, u are not accounting for these comparisons when u say the worst case constant is only 2.

Answer (score 1):

First idea that comes to my mind is using two sets. Both sets store `std::pair<index_t,value_t>` but have different ordering. (one is ordered by index and one by value). This way you can at each step iterating trough array find minimum (first element in set ordered by values) and what element/pair to remove from both sets (first element in set ordered by index) . At each step you add pair in each set and remove pair from each set.

Comment: It has `O(n log n)` time complexity, not `O(n)`.

Comment: More precisely it is  O (n * log(k) )